# How to use a heredoc in a security group description

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying this:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "mysg" {
  description = <<EOF
this is a very long descirpltion slkfjsldkfjsdf
skdfjlskdfjlksdjlfksdjlfksjdlfksjdlfkjsdlkfjsldkf
sdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlksdjflskdfjlksdjflksdjflksdf
EOF
}
```

getting this

> aws_security_group.mysq: Error creating Security Group: InvalidParameterValue: Invalid security group description. Valid descriptions are strings less than 256 characters from the following set:  a-zA-Z0-9. _-:/()#,@[]+=&;{}!$*

It is well within the char limit I think it's adding carriage returns or something? How do I have it not add line breaks to the string?

I also tried variations of `-` to no avail https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/issues/144

Comment: no `return` ( `\n` ) accepted.

Comment: what does that mean and what am i doing wrong and is there a fix? I also tried to use `-`

Comment: did you read the answer (the last comment) you pasted? https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/issues/144#issuecomment-435455048

Comment: yes that didnt work and the syntax he' s using isn't even correct according to the devs

Answer (score 0):

As the link you pasted, the [last comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/issues/144#issuecomment-435455048) has provided the workaround.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "mysg" {
  description = <<-EOF
this is a very long descirpltion slkfjsldkfjsdf
skdfjlskdfjlksdjlfksdjlfksjdlfksjdlfkjsdlkfjsldkf
sdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlksdjflskdfjlksdjflksdjflksdf
-EOF
}
```

Here is the dry-run output

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  + aws_security_group.mysg
      id:                     <computed>
      arn:                    <computed>
      description:            "this is a very long descirpltion slkfjsldkfjsdf\nskdfjlskdfjlksdjlfksdjlfksjdlfksjdlfkjsdlkfjsldkf\nsdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlksdjflskdfjlksdjflksdjflksdf\n"
      egress.#:               <computed>
      ingress.#:              <computed>
      name:                   <computed>
      owner_id:               <computed>
      revoke_rules_on_delete: "false"
      vpc_id:                 <computed>


Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: and you confirmed that works for you because as stated in my post it did not for me

Comment: what terraform version did you run with?

Comment: `Terraform v0.11.10`

Comment: should be fine, interesting.

Comment: you run on windows or Macos/linux?

Comment: ohhh dry run will succeed, plan worked for me, it failed on apply. And I can try again later to confirm I didn't have typo in my indentation or something

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it looks like the use of the heredoc is breaking the length limit here. You could just not use the heredoc but if Verbosity is your thing......

add a file called description.txt with you blessed works:

e.g.

```
This is a very long descirpltion slkfjsldkfjsdf
skdfjlskdfjlksdjlfksdjlfksjdlfksjdlfkjsdlkfjsldkf
sdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlksdjflskdfjlksdjflksdjflksdf
```

then change your code to:

```
data "local_file" "foo" {
    filename = "${path.module}/description.txt"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "mysg" {
  description = "${data.local_file.foo.content}"
}
```

Fill your boots.